# Python cmd timer creation

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class OCP(cmd.Cmd):
    intro = 'Welcome to the  OCP shell.   Type help or ? to list commands.\n'
    prompt = '> '
    file = None

    def do_connect(self, arg):
        'connect'

        logging.debug('> connect')
        connect()
```

I have this code that uses cmd from python. What I want is to run a timer everytime the user enters connect for 30 secs.
If after the 30 secs the user still didn't type anything, it prints a "disconnected" state.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started...

```
import time

time.sleep(30)

print('Disconnected')
```

Afiak there is no monitor for "any" key press without `input()`, which stops your code from running.